# MomentJS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Tags: momentjs

In my angular application, Following code to parse the date using moment gives the error

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible" -

```
moment('Mon 16-Dec-19', 'ddd DD-MMM-YY', true);
```

If I remove the strict check it works -

```
moment('Mon 16-Dec-19', 'ddd DD-MMM-YY');
```

It is surprising because it was working 2 weeks ago and suddenly I got this error during the development.

I have checked my package.json and no version change for moment.

Comment: are you using different languages? "ddd" is dependent on localization

Comment: I am using the two different date format. The default one is 'ddd DD-MMM-YY'

Comment: are you using [moment.locale](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) other then English in your application?

Comment: No. I am not using it.